# Error in Vercel deployment with OffCanvas

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, github, vercel, off-canvas-menu

From the beginning of my project, in visual studio I have added Bootstrap to my project, and using the offcanvas component for my react app. If I run my project in localhost I have no problem and the off canvas works. But now I have decided to host my React project on Vercel. So I connected my GitHub add the repository and form Vercel select the folder where my project is. At the moment that I start the deploy on Vercel, in the first section "Building", I receive an error:

> Failed to compile.
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/OffCanvas' in '/vercel/path0/src/components'
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I have no idea of why i recieve this error. Please help me :)

I have tried to reinstall Bootstrap from my project and update it on GitHub but nothing changed. I have also tried to reinstall node_modules and execute this command `npm run build`. Nothing changed--Vercel shows me the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. You might set your browser's spell checker to English to avoid the many errors I fixed for you.

Comment: Note that the component is spelled "Offcanvas", not "OffCanvas".